# Android - send data to server with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, upload

I was following this tutorial to upload images with android: [here](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

After the line `conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);` in function uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) I added further lines with `conn.setRequestProperty("title", "example"); conn.setRequestProperty("name", "simple_image");` but in the php file I am not receiving these strings with $_POST or $_GET only the image is uploaded.

Is this tutorial [here](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) only for uploading images?

I would like to send with the image some other data too. How could I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes that tutorial is for uploading a single file only.If you want to send some other data(may be some strings) along with your image, then you can use [MultipartEntityBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html).However to use this you need to download the jars from the [Apache HttpComponents site](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and add them to project and path(just add the `httpclient` jar to your `libs` folder).

Now for uploading an image along with some string data you can use (may be inside `doInBackground` of your `AsynTask`)

```
File file = new File("yourImagePath");
String urlString = "http://yoursite.com";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
/* setting a HttpMultipartMode */
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
/* adding an image part */
FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file);
builder.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
builder.addPart("user", new StringBody("Some String",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));//adding a string
HttpEntity reqEntity = builder.build();
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpEntity resultEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(resultEntity);
```

P.S : I assumed you are using `AsyncTask` for uploading process and that's the reason i said to use this code inside `doInBackground` of your `AsyncTask`.

You can use [MultipartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) too.Follow [this tutorial](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/) which describes how to upload multiple images along with some other string data using `MultipartEntity`.However there's not much difference in the implementation of `MultipartEntity` and `MultipartEntityBuilder`.Try yourself to learn both.Hope these info help you.